# converting SQL to Eloquent or other db engine in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I've got a query like that:

```
select av.id as idd, login as start_time, logout as end_time, av.app_name as app, av.machine_name, sum(cast(ai.app_stage as unsigned)) as points, pc.name as place from application_visits as av 
LEFT JOIN application_interactions as ai 
    on ai.app_name = av.app_name
    and av.machine_name = ai.machine_name
    and ai.date between av.login and av.logout 
    and ai.type = 'points'
LEFT JOIN devices as dv
    on dv.machine_name = av.machine_name
LEFT JOIN places as pc
    on dv.place_id = pc.id
where av.user_id = '123'
group by av.id, pc.name
order by place;
```

And I have to use them on two deployment servers, one using MySQL and other PostgreSQL. The problem is when I'm aggregating 'points' column I have to cast them as INT in PG and cast as unsigned (or leave it) in MySQL.

I've used Eloquent a little bit but and  I wanted to abstract it, but I never converted to it from SQL, nor the other way around. What would be the best way to approach it? Can I easily convert it to Eloquent or some other query builder or maybe can I check which SQL I'm using and then execute one of two queries?

Comment: You can go for either solution and it will be fine i guess, laravel elequent query builder is really easy to understand if you have sql knowledge already and it helps being more easly extendable. That said, you can also do the second solution by checking the `config('database.default')` value ,

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to use a tool called [Orator](http://www.midnightcowboycoder.com/) that can convert your raw SQL query to Query Builder syntax. This is the output after running it on your SQL query:

```
DB::select(`av.id as idd`,`login as start_time`,`logout as end_time`,`av.app_name as app`,`av.machine_name`,`pc.name as place`)
        ->addSelect(DB::raw(`sum(cast) as points`))
        ->from(`application_visits as av`)
        ->join(`application_interactions as ai`, function($join) {
            $join->on(`ai.app_name`, `=`, `av.app_name`)
                ->on(`av.machine_name`, `=`, `ai.machine_name`)
                ->on(`ai.date`, `between`, `av.login`)
                ->on(`av.logout`)
                ->on(`ai.type`, `=`, `points`);
            })
        ->join(`devices as dv`, function($join) {
            $join->on(`dv.machine_name`, `=`, `av.machine_name`);
            })
        ->join(`places as pc`, function($join) {
            $join->on(`dv.place_id`, `=`, `pc.id`);
            })
        ->where(`av.user_id`, `=`, 123)
        ->groupBy(`av.id`)
        ->groupBy(`pc.name`)
        ->orderByRaw(`place ASC`)
        ->get();
```

This will return a collection with your results, I haven't run this code myself however but it might be a place to start and then you can debug from there and iterate upon your solution.

Comment: One thing to note is that you will have to replace the backticks (`) into strings.